# what's the meaning of "up" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

we have, at present, 130 plaques **up** in the city. Does it mean it could be more than 130 plaques?

Comment: A plaque is something that is put "up" on a wall.

Answer (score 1):

"Up" is simply short for "put up", "placed up", "nailed up", "hung up", or various other ways of attaching things to surfaces (or otherwise displaying them).  "Up" suggests that they are *off the ground*, and *easily visible*.  Example:

> She is a famous artist, with many of her paintings (hung) **up** in museums around the world.

Comment: It may seem like quibbling, but to say that **up** is "short for" some other phrase is really not what's happening.  A planner of an outdoor concert might say "We made sure to **have** many outdoor toilets **around**".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I think this is right. I'm more inclined to see "have up" as its own informal type of phrasal verb. So I would say that this sentence is just a little tricky because the object (130 plaques) is breaking up the phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1):

> we have, at present, 130 plaques up in the city. Does it mean it could be more than 130 plaques?

No.  The correct way to mean that is to say "We have, at present, up to 130 plaques in the city".

*Up* here is simply being used to mean they mounted up on something such as poles, etc. as though there were an implied "that are" between *plaques* and *in the city*.